# Get tables whose wcu/rcu 200 or 200+ using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Is there any way to get table wcu/rcu value using boto3,
I have 200+ tables from which I need to list out tables whose wcu/rcu values are set to 200 or 200+, so looking for solution using boto3 if i can get these tables, as some tables are on demand and some have been provisioned throughput enable.
I really don't want to do this manually,
Code I tried is:

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table("table-name")
billing_mode = table.billing_mode_summary
print(billing_mode)
```

but this doesn't provided desired output.
Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get table wcu/rcu value using boto3

You can use `dynamodb.describe_table` like this:

```
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
...
table_info = dynamodb.describe_table(TableName="table-name")['Table']
wcu = table_info['ProvisionedThroughput']['WriteCapacityUnits']
rcu = table_info['ProvisionedThroughput']['ReadCapacityUnits']
... Your conditions to verify the values...
```

For more details check [DynamoDB.Client.describe_table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.describe_table)